# "Item not available" error when trying to upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-appstore, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Macbook Pro late 2011 from Sierra to High Sierra via this link:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?ls=1&mt=12

However, when it opens the itunes store shows this error:

[image: 1]

To be safe I tried it with the Mojave update via this link here:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?ls=1&mt=12

and it gave me the same error. I read on this [forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8400675?answerId=33433267022#33433267022) (and tried their solutions) that this might mean that it's not available for me to download. Where can I download the High Sierra update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend opening these links in Safari so they translate easier to the correct App Store app.

- https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314
- https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741

I removed the US store from the High Sierra link and cribbed the Catalina link from another answer. Also, once you get the download set, other issues can crop up. This following link is a compendium of knowledge and is super useful for reference.

- [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: It is my pleasure! That error is hard to figure out for many people at work. So glad you’re back in business.